# Why my mongoose request returns a query but not result data, user information in, in my case?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I don't know why it doesn't work for me now, but it did work earlier.

I need to retrieve information from my db. I can easily save data using Model.create but when I want to get data I get:

```
Query {
  _mongooseOptions: {},
  _transforms: [],
  _hooks: Kareem { _pres: Map {}, _posts: Map {} },
  _executionCount: 0,
  mongooseCollection: NativeCollection {
    collection: Collection { s: [Object] },
    Promise: [Function: Promise],
    opts: {
      bufferCommands: true,
      capped: false,
      Promise: [Function: Promise],
      '$wasForceClosed': undefined
    },
    name: 'users',
    collectionName: 'users',
    conn: NativeConnection {
      base: [Mongoose],
      collections: [Object],
      models: [Object],
      config: [Object],
      replica: false,
      options: null,
      otherDbs: [],
      relatedDbs: {},
      states: [Object],
      _readyState: 1,
      _closeCalled: false,
      _hasOpened: true,
      plugins: [],
      _listening: false,
      _connectionOptions: [Object],
      client: [MongoClient],
      '$initialConnection': [Promise],
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      name: 'test_name',
      host: 'cocoondb-shard-00-02-qx9lu.mongodb.net',
      port: 27017,
      user: 'test',
      pass: '1234',
      db: [Db]
    },

 ...
```

I have only one route and use graphql apollo server.

my express route is:

server.js (main file - enterpoint)

```
import confirmRoute from '../src/routes/confirm';  

const app = express();
app.use('/confirm', confirmRoute);
```

confirm.js

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import SimpleCrypto from 'simple-crypto-js';
import { env } from '../../environment';
import { User } from '../models/user.model';

const secret = env.TOKEN_SECRET;
const router = Router();

router.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  const crypter = new SimpleCrypto(secret);
  const id = crypter.decrypt(req.url.slice(1));

  const user = User.find({ id }, callback => callback);
  res.status(200).send(`Hello, your email confirmed successfully : ${id}`);

})

module.exports = router;
```

schema

```
import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose';

const userSchema = new Schema({
  firstname: { type: String, required: [false, 'firstname address required'] },
  lastname: { type: String, required: [false, 'lastname address required'] },
  email: { type: String, required: [true, 'email address required'] },
  password: { type: String, required: [true, 'password required'] },
  confirmed: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  instagram: { type: String, default: "" },
  facebook: { type: String, default: "" },
  role: { type: String }
}, { timestamps: true });

export const User = model('user', userSchema, 'users');
```

What am I doing wrong here? 
I apologise if my question is silly...

Comment: Where is the query?

Comment: @SuleymanSah ,  User.findOne({id: ‘1’}), I tried like this and User.findOne({Id:’1’}, callback => callback), and with exec()

Comment: Can you add all route code to the question, also mongoose schema?

Comment: @SuleymanSah added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are not actually executing the query.

Please try one of this solutions to make it work.

Also I used `findById`, but it does not matter, you can continue to query with findOne also.

Alternative 1:  then catch blocks:

```
router.get("/users/:id", (req, res) => {
  User.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(doc => {
      res.send(doc);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).send("something went wrong");
    });
});
```

Alternative 2:  callback

```
router.get("/users/:id", (req, res) => {
  User.findById(req.params.id, (err, doc) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).send("something went wrong");
    }

    return res.send(doc);
  });
});
```

Alternative 3:  async/await

```
router.get("/users/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let result = await User.findById(req.params.id);
    res.send(result);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(500).send("something went wrong");
  }
});
```

To apply your case:

```
router.get("/*", (req, res) => {
  const crypter = new SimpleCrypto(secret);
  const id = crypter.decrypt(req.url.slice(1));

  console.log("id: ", id);

  User.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(doc => {
      console.log("doc: ", doc);
      res.status(200).send(`Hello, your email confirmed successfully : ${id}`);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).send("something went wrong");
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, I tired to catch it with try catch but there was no error. I’ll try async way too

Comment: I tried on different methods: find, findOne, findById

Comment: I understand that the problem is something silly but I cannot see what’s the issue

Comment: @Valaryo please bu sure that you are getting the id correctly, first use a static existing id.

Comment: Log the id before the query, and check if it exists in users collection.

Comment: Tried it. Pasted the id in

Comment: @Valaryo and what happened?

Comment: And get that Query object but not the user I was trying to catch. The funny thing I can add a user into a db

Comment: @Valaryo please use the Alternative 2 (I updated the answer), and be sure your id is correct.

Comment: I copied and pasted your three alternatives and they all work. I was doing something wrong .... do these all alternatives: callback, Promise and async work with all methods: find, findById, findByIdAndUpdate, and others?

Comment: by the way, I tried to use findByIdAndUpdate but it said that it's deprecated. What is the best and fastest way to update some fields?

Comment: @Valaryo to remove those deprecations use this code where you mongoose.connect like this  ` mongoose.set("useFindAndModify", false);`